# Unable to Ping Web Service via JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to write some JavaScript that calls a Web Service I've created. This web service is part of another

```
function ping() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://myserver/OtherSite/ping?$format=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    type: "GET",
    success: ping_Succeeded,
    error: ping_Failed
  });
}

function ping_Succeeded(result) {
  alert("success");
}

function ping_Failed(e1, e2, e3) {
  console.log(e1 + "\n" + e2 + "\n" + e3);
}
```

When I execute this code, I notice in Fiddler that my request to my web service is fine. A 200 is returned. The JSON that I am expecting is there. However, in the JavaScript console, I see an error that says: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token:".

In looking in the console, I noticed the following: "message: "jQuery18209005181000102311_1352904505837 was not called".

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thank you

Comment: try taking the $ out of $format

Comment: is it a jsonp endpoint, or does it return json?

Comment: "The JSON that I am expecting is there". Care to share it?

Comment: The JSON is pretty basic. Just a test. The JSON is: {
  "d":{ "result":"Test 37" } }

Comment: @user687554 Where does the code crash? Do you reach `ping_Succeeded` or `ping_Failed`?

Comment: @chrislhardin - I tried removing the $. However, then XML is returned.

Comment: @hvgotcodes - The endpoint returns json. I thought JSPONP was for cross-domain stuff. Regardless, do I just need to remove JSONP?

Comment: I think it may be that you are asking for JSONP which requires the JSON result to be escaped. It's been a while since I've done this though so I am not sure.

Comment: @user687554 - I reach ping_Failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing to wrap your JSON into callback call. 
Because of `dataType:"jsonp"` jquery will send request to an URL like this:

```
OtherSite/ping?$format=json&callback=jQuery18204326352379284799_1352906037982&_=1352906037995
```

So, you must take a name from callback and wrap your response like this (on server):

```
 jQuery18204326352379284799_1352906037982({ "d":{ "result":"Test 37" } })
```

Or you can try to replace `dataType:"jsonp"` with `dataType:"json"`

Comment: I tried changing "jsonp" to "json" and I received an error that says: "XMLHttpWebRequest cannot load [url] Origin [domain] is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  I do not fully understand what you mean by "take a name from callback and wrap..." Can you show me how that would change my existing request?

Comment: If so, than you should just take callback value from GET request and add it your response, so it will look like JS function call with object passed to it. In PHP it would be like: `$callbackname = $_GET['callback']; echo $callbackname. "(" . $json_response . ")";`

Comment: Or here you can take a look at how Access-Control-Allow-Origin could be fixed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control (basically, you should confgiure your server so it will allow ajax requests from other domains)